# How can I use different themes for mobile and main versions Yii?

Tags: yii

I have Yii project with main and mobile versions. Views files of mobile version has path
modules/mobile/views/nameController/ . For main version created theme, all views loading from path themes/nameTheme. In config writed 'theme' => 'nameTheme', and in controller I use code:

```
public function init() {
       ...
        Yii::app()->theme = 'mobile';
       ...
        return parent::init();
    }
```

I moved files of mobile versions to new theme. But Yii loaded views from modules/mobile/views/nameController/. I don't know how define theme for mobile versions in config. Can I use other theme for mobile version in my project (together with theme for main version)? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do my dynamic theme switching, I have method within my Controller component that determines what kind of browser the client uses and then set the theme from within the 'init' method. Very similar to what you've done.

I think the difference is in file organization. If you have separate view files for your desktop and mobile themes, I'd suggest that you place the view files withing the respective theme directories.

I usually make use of a single markup for my themes and just modify the style sheets for both the desktop and mobile themes so I have to worry about it once.

Here's how I do it:

```
public function isMobileBrowser()
{
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    return preg_match('/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4));
}
```

And this is my Controller::init method :

```
public function init()
{
    if ($this->isMobileBrowser()) {
        Yii::app()->theme = "mobile-white-blue";
    }
            parent::init();   
}
```

If you have multiple view files scattered around your application, Yii looks first for the view files within your theme folder: AppRoot>>Themes>>{theme_name}>>views and if it can't find it there, Yii looks in the primary view folder: AppRoot>>protected>>views or if it's a module view, AppRoot>>protected>>modules>>{module_name}>>views

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thank to the help! I try your method, dynamic theme switching is good idea.